# How to create an AES encrypted, single segment, HLS from an .mov using Shaka Packager

Tags: aes, http-live-streaming, m3u8

Can anyone provide me with an example command that will create AES encrypted, single-segment HLS files from an .mov using Shaka Packager?

Answer (score 0):

Received a message from the Shaka-Packager devs and this is not possible as of v1.5.1.